# Load data from related entities using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have two tables `product` and `Images`. They have a one-to-many relationship. I want to display product name and all its related images in the view, I am using repository pattern. I am new to MVC and Linq please help. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code....

```
public partial class tbl_Product
{
        public int pro_id { get; set; }
        public string pro_name { get; set; }
        public string pro_desc { get; set; }
        public string pro_model { get; set; }
        public string pro_dimensions { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> pro_UnitsInStock { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> pro_price { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> pro_oldprice { get; set; }
  
        public virtual ICollection<tbl_Images> tbl_Images { get; set; }
}
```

ProductRepository class:

```
public ProductDetail GetProductByID(int id)
{
    var product = this.storeDB.tbl_Product.Where(x => x.pro_id == id).FirstOrDefault();   
                                      
    return product;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `Include` clause to load the related images:

```
public ProductDetail GetProductByID(int id)
{
    var product = storeDB.tbl_Product
                         .Where(x => x.pro_id == id)
                         .Include(p => p.tbl_Images)
                         .FirstOrDefault();   
                                      
    return product;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, now i am stuck at posting these values to the contoller method. Because var product cannot return ProductDetail.....please help

Comment: That's a whole new question - and if you do ask - please also post all relevant details (like definition of your `ProductDetail` class) so we stand a chance to actually help - thanks!

Comment: I have posted a new question regarding this issue. thanks